# How to show PHP validation error message that is received in Ajax response in a HTML form

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, json, ajaxform

I am receiving valid json response when the form is not submitted (when the validation fails)
I can print it in console. I am struggling to show that validation error message to the HTML form under or next to the proper field.

**my form**

```
<form action="" method="post" name="contact-me" id="profile-update" class="requires-validation">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">  
        <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
        <div class="d-flex form-floating mb-0 flex-fill">    
            <input name="yourname" type="text" class="form-control name" placeholder="Type your name" >
            <label for="yourname" class="form-label">Your Name</label>
            <div class="nameerror">Name field is valid!</div>
        </div>
    </div>    

    <div class="d-flex flex-row align-items-center mb-4">  
        <i class="fas fa-key fa-lg me-3 fa-fw"></i>
        <div class="d-flex form-floating mb-0 flex-fill">   
            <input name="email"  type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Type a valid email" >
            <label for="email" class="form-label">Your Email</label>
            <div class="emailerror">Name field is valid!</div>
        </div>    
    </div>

    <div class="d-flex justify-content-center mx-4 mb-3 mb-lg-4">
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" id="submit">Send message!</button>
    </div>
    <div id="nds_form_feedback"></div>
</form>
```

So I want to show the name validation error message in `<div class="nameerror">Name field is valid!</div>` and email validation error message in `<div class="emailerror">Name field is valid!</div>`

**my validation**

```
<?php 
   function prfl_update_validation_func(){
    $errors = array();
    $response = array();

    $yourname=$_POST['yourname']; 
    $yourname=$_POST['email']; 

    if ((empty($_POST['yourname'])) ) {
        $errors['yourname'] = "Please enter your name"; 
    } 

    if ((!empty($_POST['yourname'])) && (!preg_match("/^[a-zA-Z-' ]*$/",($_POST['yourname'])))) {
        $errors['yourname'] = "Special characters or spaces are not allowed in the username";    
    }
    
    if ((empty($_POST['email'])) ) {
        $errors['email'] = "Please enter your email";    
    } 

    $response['errors'] = $errors;

     if($errors) {

        $response['success'] = false;
        $response['message'] = "Fail";

    } else {

        $reponse['success'] = true;
        $response['message'] = "<div class='alert alert-success'>Article added</div>";
    }

    echo json_encode($response);
    wp_die();
  }
```

So all my form validation errors are in `$response['errors'] = $errors;` right?

now, **Ajax** part. please read the commented lines as well

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).on('click', '#submit', function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var fd = new FormData();

        fd.append('action', 'prfl_update_validation_func');   

        jQuery.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: ajax_url,
            data: fd,
            contentType: false, //because I have a file upload feild as well
            processData: false, //because I have a file upload feild as well
            headers: {Accept : "application/json;charset=utf-8"},
            debug:true,
            success: function(response) {
                if(response.type == "success") {
                   jQuery("#nds_form_feedback").html('Sucessfully Sent'); // if the form passes the validation this works fine
                }
                else {
                    alert("Not Uploaded"); // shows the popup correctly if there is a validation error
                   
                    jQuery("#nds_form_feedback").html('boooooooooooo'); // this replace the div #nds_form_feedback correctly if there is a validation error
                    
                    jQuery("#nds_form_feedback").html("<ul><li>"+errors.email+"</li></ul>"); // this says 'errors' is not defined

                    console.log(response);

                }
             }
       
    });
});

</script>
```

what I want here is showing the correct validation error message under/next to it's input fields.

`jQuery("#nds_form_feedback").html("<ul><li>"+errors.email+"</li></ul>");` this needs to be replaced with correct classes and with correct array values.

**[EDIT]**
json response I am getting in console

```
{
  "errors": {
    "yourname": "Please enter your name",
    "email": "Please enter your email"
  },
  "success": false,
  "message": "Fail"
}
```

Please help.

[**EDIT after correcting** the code as per @cbroe and @sudhir-bastakoti , I am getting the following response now]

```
{
  "errors": {
    "yourname": "Please enter your name",
    "email": "Please enter your email"
  },
  "success": false,
  "message": "Fail"
}
```

Comment: First of all, your first form field appears to be named `name`, not `yourname` - so access the correct parameter, and use the correct name for what you put into $errors as well.

Comment: And then, use those keys from the `errors` property of your JSON on the client, to select the corresponding field (attribute selector), go up to the parent element, and then find the `.nameerror` element in there.

Comment: as per the console response you shared, your response does not have property `type`, so instead of `if(response.type == "success") {` check for `if(response.success) {`

Comment: you are always return 200 as status code so `response.type == "success"` is always true. You should check if `response.errors.length === 0` or `response.success`

Comment: And it's response.errors not just errors

Comment: thanks guys. I edited code to post here and missed the field name. made an update to the original question. All these suggestions are for how to get the response correctly. Mainly, I want to how to show those error messages in the proper place/line.

@CBroe can you create a sample code based on your second comment please?

Comment: @R4ncid if I change the code to ```if(response.error) {
                                   jQuery("#nds_form_feedback").html('Not sent!!!');
                                   console.log(response);
                                }``` nothing happens. no console message or no div replacement

Comment: Something like `$.each(response.errors, function(key, val) {
  $('#profile-update [name="'+key+'"]').parent().find('.'+key+'error').html(val);
});`

Comment: @CBroe thanks but it does not print anything even in console. I tried like this https://prnt.sc/GCIazu0GjOvs

Comment: Then I guess you probably put this in the wrong place, at least the second part should give you something on console, if `response.errors` actually was an object at this point.

Comment: @CBroe if I directly use like this ```console.log(response);``` I see this in console https://prnt.sc/4mvX93ZNflbR - seems strange?

Comment: Looks like you got a string value there, and not an actual object - because jQuery did not recognize the response was JSON. Either add an appropriate Content-Type header to your server response, or set `dataType: 'json'` in your AJAX options

Comment: Worked after I added ```header("Content-Type: application/json", true);``` to the bottom of the validation function. The out put is https://prnt.sc/lQ0P086D-ygY  
Thank you so much. the correct answer to the original question is your 3rd reply. make it as an answer. I'll accept.